# Android file uploads - FTP or better alternative?

Tags: android, ftp

I'm writing an Android app that requires the upload of small txt files to a web site. I've used FTP for this and it works fine, but I have a couple of questions:

1. Firstly, is this the best way to
   upload files
2. Will there be an issue
   with 1000+ simultaneous uploads from
   different devices?

Any help would be great!

Comment: I think its fine. There will be no issue, unless your server doesn't have the capacity to handle 1000+ simultaneous uploads from different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a webserver, which will handle POST/GET requests.

Then just send the file content via HTTP and save it to the disk with an application running on the server.